# Where to put the file and how to compile and run it?

Tags: c, linux

I want to learn how to write a C program under Linux. Now I have installed Centos, and I'm using `vim` to write a 'hello world' program in the C language. But I don't know where to put it, or how to compile it? I have installed `gcc`. I am sorry. I am a newbie. Thank you. Could you make me an example how to write a simple program in C then test and compile it.?

Comment: I recommend you create a directory to put your source code in: `cd; mkdir src; cd src; ...run vim and gcc and your programs...`.  Cluttering up your top level (home) directory is not a good idea in the long term.  Also, don't do your programming logged in as root; there are too many easy ways to wreck your entire system by accident like that.  Do as little as possible as root.

Comment: if don't put the code in  (home) directory ,which  directory  do you suggest and like to put the code in? thank you

Comment: I suggested to create yourself a source directory (I use `src` which is hallowed by ancient tradition, but you can use any name you like). The minuscule bit of shell script could be rewritten: `mkdir $HOME/src; cd $HOME/src; ...do work...`. The idea is that your home directory should contain sub-directories (such as a `bin` directory for the commands you develop for your own use), and hidden files such as `.profile` or `.bashrc`, and probably nothing else. I have 60 visible files or directories in my $HOME; 5 of them are files, and I should really clean those up. I have about 100 hidden files.

Answer (score 2):

Save it anywhere, then in a terminal run

`gcc path/to/file.c`

That's all it takes. The default output will be a file called `a.out` which you can run directly from the terminal.

If you're uncomfortable with the terminal (though since you're using vim I'll assume you're not), there are many IDEs that make it even easier for beginners.

Comment: coulde you make me an example. many thanks

Answer (score 2):

type this in your terminal:

```
$ mkdir ~/learnC
$ cd ~/learnC
$ cat > hello.c 

   #include <stdio.h> 
   int main () { 
      printf("Hello World\n"); 
   } 

/* Press Ctrl+D */

$ gcc hello.c -o hello
$ ./hello
```