# Where to put the C file to compile and run

Tags: c, gcc, terminal, cygwin

I know that this question might already be on the site and I have looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10809834/where-to-put-the-file-and-how-to-compile-and-run-it), but I haven't been able to fix the issue I have been having.

Today I got a C programming book just to look into it. However, I can't get further than page 17 because I can't seem to be able to get a piece of code to compile. I'm using the Cygwin Terminal and I have tried to follow all the steps to get it to work but in the book it doesn't specify exactly how to make it compile.

The path to my script is `C:\Users\Shawn\Desktop\C\hello.c` but when I try to run it any kind of way:

```
gcc C:\Users\Shawn\Desktop\C\hello.c
```

OR

```
gcc /Users/Shawn/Desktop/C/hello.c
```

I just get the follow:

```
$ gcc C:\Users\Shawn\Desktop\C\hello.c
gcc: error: C:UsersShawnDesktopChello.c: No such file or directory
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
```

I have no idea how to get the terminal to find the correct file.

Comment: Why don't you go into that directory in the terminal and then compile? executable will create in that folder only.

Comment: What do you mean? Use C:\Users\Shawn\Desktop\C?

Comment: cd /Users/Shawn/Desktop/C

Comment: it does not seem to work.

Comment: What is not working, "cd" command is not working or is it not compiling?

Comment: In your second example you almost did it by yourself. The command should have been looked as `gcc C:/Users/Shawn/Desktop/C/hello.c`

Answer (score 0):

The shell treats the backslash character (`\`) as a an [escape](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character). Use two backslashes instead:

```
$ echo C:\Users\Shawn\Desktop\C\hello.c
C:UsersShawnDesktopChello.c

$ echo C:\\Users\\Shawn\\Desktop\\C\\hello.c
C:\Users\Shawn\Desktop\C\hello.c
```

Comment: Okay, I did that. And it found the file..but now i get a whole different error: `cygwin warning:
  MS-DOS style path detected: C:\Users\Shawn\Desktop\C\hello.c
  Preferred POSIX equivalent is: /cygdrive/c/Users/Shawn/Desktop/C/hello.c
  CYGWIN environment variable option "nodosfilewarning" turns off this warning.
  Consult the user's guide for more details about POSIX paths:
    http://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using.html#using-pathnames
`

Comment: Why don't just use slash?

Comment: @Hi-Angel Read the Wikipedia article linked in my answer.

Comment: So what? The linked Wikipedia page is about backslashes, I am talking about slash.

Comment: Try this.....Run `dos2unix` on the file `hello. c`.... It will be `dos2unix hello. c` and then complile it.